# Signing an API request for a file upload?

Tags: php, security, api, file-upload, signature

When I developed [Wave Framework](http://www.waveframework.com), I put a lot of attention on the security model for API requests. I had to make sure that the API requests can be made over HTTP from where-ever possible while at the same time secure against potential middle-man attacks, data tampering and more.

I ended up essentially building a GET string from the input data and generating a SHA-1 hash from it while salting it with API profile secret key. This works really well and protects the API as much as I need.

But my API also allows for things such as file uploads over HTTP. At the moment I am ignoring file upload related data entirely (I use it for cache signature but not for data validation). This means that a malicious middle man could technically change file contents as it is being transferred.

Are there any alternatives? Sure I could implement this when files are sent server side (such as calculate file contents as part of the validation hash), but that is not an option if the upload is through web browser and initiated through JavaScript?

How have other frameworks handled this? I've tried to search but could not find enough information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, your framework creates a web page where users may upload files. The only way to protect against man-in-the-middle in this scenario would be to use ssl.

Remember that a man-in-the-middle in this case also would be able to change the web page the user is interacting with when he uploads the data. Say that you created a javascript that in some way encrypted the document using a password that the user typed in. The man-in-the-middle could easily change the javascript to encrypt his fake document and throw away the real document.

If security is an issue on web and you need to protect against man-in-the-middle, then SSL is a requirement. There is no way around it.

Comment: Not really an answer I was looking for, but I suppose that SSL is really the only thing that can help in this situation.